# Multiple linked graphs in single report using BusinessObjects

Tags: reporting, business-objects

Is it possible to create a report which will contain multiple linked graphs?

If yes - how ?

Example – One report contains 4 graphs on a single page. Now when I try to drill down in one of the graph, information should reflect in other graphs accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Click check box to turn on the drill options setting labeled "Synchronize drill on report blocks" in the Infoview Preferences for Web Intelligence.  This will cause all blocks in any report which share a dimension to be synchronized on drill.  The Webi Rich Client has an equivalent option for changing it's behavior.

Unfortunately this isn't a per-block or per-report or per-document setting.  It is implemented as a user preference across all reports accessed and must be set for each individual which will be viewing the report.